# Why did Armand have to give Katherine money for custody rights to Val?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-birdcage

In [*The Birdcage*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0115685/), Armand makes a comment to Katherine that he got his son as a "trade" for giving Katherine money to start her business.

> **Armand**:  you've done well.
>
> **Katherine**:  Because of you. The money you gave me started this place.
>   You should have gotten stock for it.
>
> **Armand**:  I got Val for it. It was a fair trade.

**Did Armand really give Katherine money for full custody and parental rights of Val?**

Later in this conversation, Katherine admits to not being maternal, so she wouldn't have wanted Val to begin with.

> I haven't done much for him in the last 20 years. I'm not exactly
>   maternal.

**Why did Armand have to give her money if she didn't want Val in the first place?**

Comment: It's less about whether she really wanted to be a mother, as much as knowing that, if he DID want to be a or the parent, and she's legally entitled to equal custody, then that's something they don't need to "give" away. Divorces can be really, really ugly.

Comment: Damn, I'm thinking of Ms Doubtfire! I'm going to delete almost all of my comments....

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there was a formal agreement or even any intent of a trade - it's just when Katherine and Armand went there separate ways it ended up that Katherine got the money/business, and Armand got Val. "It was a fair trade" is being used figuratively - Armand feels he did well by taking full custody of Val.